# How to set state of an array without deleting old array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, state

I'm trying to amend fetched array items to a state that already contains items (I will implement pagination).

However, when I try to use code similar to `setMovies((prevMovies) => [...prevMovies, ...arr1])` I get a Typescript error `Argument of type 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type '((value: Movie[]) => Movie[] | PromiseLike<Movie[]>) | null | undefined'.`

Here fetch method is called (This is the code snippet I'd like to change):

```
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState<Movie[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchAllMovies(1)
      .then(setMovies)
      .catch(() => setMovies([]));
  }, []);
```

Here is the function called:

```
export async function fetchAllMovies(pageNumber?: number): Promise<Movie[]> {

  return await fetch(
    `${movieApiBaseUrl}/movie/popular?api_key=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}&page=${pageNumber}`
    )
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((res) => mapListResult(res.results))
    .catch(() => {
      return [];
    });
  }
  
  // = movie has to be after const {} here
  function mapListResult(res: any[]): Movie[] {
    return res.map((movie) => {
      const {
        id,
        title,
        vote_average,
        overview,
        poster_path,
        date,
      } = movie;
      return {
        id: id,
        title: title,
        vote_average: vote_average,
        description: overview,
        poster_path: poster_path ? `${posterBaseUrl}${poster_path}` : noImage,
        date: date,
      };
    });
  }


export interface Movie {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  vote_average: number;
  description: string;
  poster_path?: string;
  date: string;
}
```

How can I solve it? Thanks!

Comment: try `setMovies([...movies, ...arr1])`

Comment: I think you've mistaken something into type

Comment: The problem is that nothing can be set between the brackets, only `.then(setMovies)` is allowed

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work.

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetchAllMovies(1)
  .then((newMovies) => setMovies([...movies, ...newMovies]))
  .catch(() => setMovies([]));
}, []);
```